# Converting Mathematica to $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex, conversion

Is there a *Mathematica*-to-$\LaTeX$ converter, so that I can place *Mathematica* code, including things like `A // MatrixForm`, just as they are in the console straight into a $\LaTeX$ document?

Comment: Check out `TexForm` in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html).

Comment: Also there is File > Save As > TeX

Answer (score 30):

`TeXForm` is indeed your friend. It even gives you nicely formatted code:

```
Table[RandomInteger[10], {3}, {4}] // TeXForm
```

gives

```
(* 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
     9 & 5 & 10 & 9 \\
     6 & 10 & 3 & 9 \\
     9 & 5 & 9 & 7 \\
    \end{array}
\right)
*)
```

Comment: $\overset{\infty}{\smile}$ Ohhooooo... Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work for me for `{{-3, -6, -9}, {0, -3, -6}, {3, 0, -3}, {6, 3, 0}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7}} // TeXForm`

Comment: For me, in Mathematica 10.0, that produces the expected LaTeX output.

Comment: @SEngstrom how to install this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

This works great for transferring expressions in Traditional Form.

Select an expression, Right-Click, Copy As, LaTeX. Paste it where you want.

You can even highlight part of a traditional form output and grab the LaTex. This also works for MathML in Mathematica 8.

Answer (score 2):

I represent @cyclochaotic's answer.

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. There are still problems with `TeXForm`, though. As much as I love it as I am writing a book on continued fractions, `TeXForm` has at least two problems:

1. For fractions it just uses `\frac`, and it doesn't know that for continued fractions `\frac` should be `\cfrac`. `a/(a+a/(a+a/(a+a/(a+a/b))))//TeXForm` produces output that is too squeezed. You still have to manually replace all `\frac` with `\cfrac`. `TeXForm` has no "continued fraction detector", it just treats the sub-set of continued fractions as fractions.
2. Due to the dependence on `TraditionalForm` there can undesirable re-sorting happening under the hood. `a/(a+a/(a+a/(a+a/(a+a/b))))//TeXForm` now displays the fractions on the left followed by the partial denominators. This is mathematically not wrong, but proper continued fraction notation has the partial denominators first, followed by the fractions. And unfortunately TeXForm has no options, helpful would be an option that allows the user to turn off the auto-sorting happening in TraditionalForm. Compare:

```
a/b+a

a/b+a//TraditionalForm

a/b+a//TeXForm
```

WRI apparently does not consider this a problem, for example the last example in the helpbrowser for `TraditionalForm` is `Nest[Sqrt[1 + 1/#] &, x, 10] // TraditionalForm` and look how that differs from the original `Nest[Sqrt[1 + 1/#] &, x, 10]`